# How to get android bluetooth inputstream without an established connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

We are actually writing an app for a medical device, which is not supporting "Bluetooth Health", so we need a normal bluetooth connection to the device. The device sends a echorequest to our device, which we have to answer with the matching echo, so that we can connect to the HealthDevice.

Actually we got the problem, that we cant send the message after connecting to the device, because thats just to late. We need the outputStream of the HealthDevice, so that we can determine the right moment to answer with our string.

Our bluetooth Code is based on the Android BluetoothChat example, they are opening the in-and output streams right after connecting, but we need to open them before connecting.

I hope that you've got a solution how to get all bluetooth messages, without an established connection.